# Prevent cmake from using certain CPU features

Tags: cmake, fasttext

I am buiding fastText library on one machine, but run it on another machine with a different CPU. I am building it this way:

```
mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make && make install
```

When I run it on another machine, I get "Illegal instruction" error. By comparing outputs of /proc/cpuinfo I found out that the latter machine does not support the following CPU flags:

```
ss nonstop_tsc aperfmperf 3dnowprefetch rsb_ctxsw tsc_adjust hle
rtm mpx avx512f rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb avx512cd xsavec xgetbv1 ida arat
```

How can I prevent cmake (or make) from using those features? I want to be able to compile the library on one machine and be able to use it on another.

Comment: You can set appropirate compiler flags. For example, if your compiler is gcc and you want to limit cpu features to skylake architecture: `cmake -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS='-march=skylake' -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-march=skylake' ..`

Comment: @gudok how do I know what is the architecture of my CPU? `/proc/cpuinfo` only returns this information `vendor_id : GenuineIntel
cpu family : 6
model : 79
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2686 v4 @ 2.30GHz
stepping : 1
microcode : 0xb00002a
`

Comment: Search for your cpu model at [ark.intel.com](https://ark.intel.com/) or at wikipedia. Alternatively, gcc allows to enable/disable every cpu feature separately (search gcc manpage for  `-mavx` option and the like).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do a [cross compiling](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html?highlight=architecture#cross-compiling-for-linux) by specifying a toolchain for your second target. This toolchain file must be written by yourself.

For a quick test you can also overwrite `CMAKE_C_COMPILE_FEATURES` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES` in your project or the cmake call. see [cmake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html#manual:cmake-compile-features(7))